# Whether to include a random effect that is potentially collinear with a fixed effect

Tags: mixed-model, multicollinearity, ecology

I am trying to model bird migratory departure dates using linear or mixed effects models (although open to other model suggestions). I am interested in knowing whether latitude, sex, wing length (a proxy for body size) or body mass have any impact on departure dates. My data (departure dates and morphometric data for individual birds) was sampled from ~13 sites, with 7-50 birds per site (not a perfect experimental design, but that's field work for you). So my model is as follows:

depDate ~ latitude + sex + wingLength + mass

The question that I have is whether to include a random effect for the field sites, because departure dates for individuals from a single site are likely to be similar to one another. That model would look like this:

depDate ~ latitude + sex + wingLength + mass + (1|site)

The issue is that latitude and site are highly related to one another and possibly collinear - my sites are spread across Canada (from the Yukon to the Maritimes) and there is just a single site at each latitude.

Any thoughts as to whether it is appropriate to include the random effect? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, I think it would not normally be a problem to include a random site effect and latitude, if there is things about sites that make the departure vary beyond the latitude. That's because there's plenty of things that could be going on that would not be fully capture by a linear latitude term e.g.

- being next to the sea = perhaps more moderate climate,
- higher altitude = colder and thus earlier departure,
- protected by a mountain range = later departure,
- different types of plants growing in different locations,
- if you include latitude as a linear effect that may not capture the relationship exactly (perhaps the functional form is already published for some other birds or has been theoretically "derived") while you may have too little data to fit anything more complex unless you want to build in prior knowledge etc.

What might make this tricky is that you only have 13 sites and very few animals per site, in which case it may be hard to even tell whether latitude explains this more or less. I would personally be tempted to take a Bayesian approach that would allow you to incorporate prior knowledge on various things including how much departure dates could possibly vary between sites (for a start surely never more than 183 days or so, and probably a whole lot less...).

Comment: Thank you @Björn! I also looked at the distribution of latitudes amongst my sites, and they are biased in that there are more birds with latitudes around 45 degrees and fewer to either extreme (highest latitude is about 60, lowest is about 40). I will look into using a Bayesian approach...we don't have too much prior knowledge about this species (part of why I'm doing this work!)